# Visualforce IF statement with BOLD text

Tags: visualforce

I'm attempting to display bold text when my condition is true below. Is this possible?

```
<apex:outputText value="{! If(chocolate==true, child.eat, child.run) }"/>
```

Comment: you need to add a style attribute with similar condition and set the style to bold. something like this - `style="{! If(chocolate==true,  'font-weight' : 'bold', ''}"`

Comment: Hi @YsrShk, **child.eat** is a variable that contains a string value. I want to display that String value in BOLD. But you have removed **child.eat**?

Comment: No, what I am suggesting append the same in the outputText tag

Comment: My code is as follows

`<apex:outputText value="{! If(chocolate==true, child.eat, child.run) }" style="{! If(chocolate==true ,'font-weight' : 'bold','') }"/>`

But I get **Syntax error.  Missing ')'**